# ApolloConsumer update cache directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

How can I update the cache using ApolloConsumer? My goal is to remove an object from the `uploadCustomers` data in cache. Without using Mutation, but using ApolloConsumer.

In this case, there is no Mutation happening when I remove an item, so I can't use `refetchQueries` or `update(`). I only need to update the cache to remove it.

```
<ApolloConsumer>
    {({ cache }) => (
        <IconButton type="trash" onClick={() => {
            let otherItems = remove(data.uploadCustomers, function (item) {
                return item.orgnr != orgnr
            })
            console.log(otherItems)
            cache.writeData({
                data: {
                    uploadCustomers: otherItems
                }
            })
        }} />
    )}
</ApolloConsumer>
```

The console.log returns all items that are not removed.

Comment: too many things missing/unknown - `remove()`, `orgnr`

Comment: @xadm `remove()` is Lodash remove and `orgnr` is simply an ID that specifies which object should be removed.

Comment: 'simply' `orgnr` not provided ?

Comment: @xadm It is derived from the data result of the Mutation `uploadCustomers. My question is: How can I update the cache without using Mutation or Query, but using ApolloConsumer. Because in this case, there is no Mutation, I only want to update the cache.

Comment: `writeQuery` or `writeFragment` - not `writeData` ?

Comment: If using `writeQuery` I need to pass variables for the query again, and that won't work. As far as I know, it is not possible to delete a fragment using writeFrament. Reffering to: https://runkit.com/dahjelle/58ebac433425bc0014c8ec55

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865262/6124657)